# Form action in model window not working in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I tried to create a form in a model window. But the form action doesn't work. This is my code so far.

**HTML Code**

```
<form  action="functions/userManagement.php?id="<?php echo $id ?>  name='searchdata' id="comment_box"  method="get">
    <div style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">x</button>
                    <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Put the Reason for Deactivate</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="70" name="comment" form="usrform"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
                    <button  onclick="form_submit()" class="btn btn-primary" name="add" value="Proceed">Proceed</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Java Script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function form_submit() {
        document.getElementById("comment_box").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this.

Comment: what is the error on browser console ?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: When I click the submit button, It close the model instead of link to action file.

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** Your action attribute Get parameter value should be inside the double quotes .

```
action="functions/userManagement.php?id="<?php echo $id ?>
```

To

```
action="functions/userManagement.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>"
```

**2nd :** Simple change button type to submit

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="add" value="Proceed">Proceed</button>
```

**3rd :** Your form should be inside the modal .

```
           <div style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="myModal">
             <div class="modal-dialog">
               <div class="modal-content">
                <form  action="functions/userManagement.php?id="<?php echo $id ?>  name='searchdata' id="comment_box"  method="get">
               <div class="modal-header">
                 <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">x</button>
                 <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Put the Reason for Deactivate</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                 <textarea rows="4" cols="70" name="comment" form="usrform"></textarea>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
                 <button  onclick="form_submit()" class="btn btn-primary" name="add" value="Proceed">Proceed</button>
                </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Note :** simple your submiting the form . so you can submit the form easily by button type="submit" .

Comment: Your form should be inside the modal . take look on my 3rd point @ChathurikaJayawardana

Comment: I did it also. But still the same result. When I click the submit button, It close the model instead of link to action file

Comment: i think you missed something in html .that's why it's closing can you post entire page code . @ChathurikaJayawardana

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
onclick="javascript:form_submit()"
```

Use this one

```
action="<?php echo htmlentities('functions/userManagement.php?id= echo $id');?>"
```

Hope it is helpful for you.